# view pager is swiping same image again and again

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have been working on app (Question Answer based) . I have included view pager to swipe the image but it's only swiping same image .

code of class which call a class (where view pager is included in activity)

```
package com.example.joshiyogesh.puzzle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class ExerciseOneQuestionList extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_one_question_list);
    }

    public void questionOne(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ExerciseOneQuestions.class);
        intent.putExtra("question_index",0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

ExerciseOneQuestion.java

```
package com.example.joshiyogesh.puzzle;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ExerciseOneQuestions extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public int questionIndexReceive;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_one_questions);
        questionIndexReceive = getIntent().getIntExtra("question_index",1);
//        questionIndexReceive =Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("question_index"));
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

pager Adapter class

```
package com.example.joshiyogesh.puzzle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        position = new ExerciseOneQuestions().questionIndexReceive;
        Fragments fragments = new Fragments();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("question_no",position);
        fragments.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

fragments class

```
public class Fragments extends Fragment {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container ,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){

        int [] image_index = {R.drawable.eightypageanswer1,R.drawable.eightypageanswer8};
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int message = bundle.getInt("question_no");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments,container,false);
        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageQuestions);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_index[message]);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

for testing purpose I have considered only two images in integer, But its always swiping same image i.e first image.

instead of changing "question_index" in ExerciseOneQuestionList.java 
here ...

```
public void questionOne(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ExerciseOneQuestions.class);
        intent.putExtra("question_index",0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

couldn't understand why its always showing same image ?

Comment: Are you getting the first image only? Can i know the message int value you are getting each time?

Comment: @Nivedh yup i'm always getting first image i.e index 0

Comment: remove 
position = new ExerciseOneQuestions().questionIndexReceive;
this may solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem is in line

`position = new ExerciseOneQuestions().questionIndexReceive;`

It seems that position is always set on the same number.

Comment: Couldn't able to understand that if questionIndexReceive has been changed by me manually than why its not changing position according to you if problem in that line

Comment: and if there would be another way then let us tell . What actually has been done here is that image is changing inside fragments. And I have used above line because further when there would be many images , then if user would like to directly go (suppose) 10th image then that can be done directly as well as with swipe

Comment: Var `position` should never be changed. If you want to show manually image at position x you should go to that page of pager using `pager.setCurrentItem(x)`. I am not sure that I fully understand what you want to do, but this is for sure wrong way.

Comment: app based on image and answer . There are numbers written in activity if user click on any number then it would directly show that images , image of questions are stored in integer , that is accessed by fragments , in fragments we change the image . when user directly jump at particular stage(image of question) then at that place he can also swipe the images to see next or previous images , if any

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know what you are doing with this " new ExerciseOneQuestions().questionIndexReceive;" line. But in standard way you should have make two fragments then add these fragments to your adapter. Rest of thing will be done by adapter , following rough code may help you :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);    // Which Fragment should be dislpayed by the viewpager for the given position

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
}
```

Make two fragments object in class add them in adapter by calling addFragment method and then setadapter.

Comment: i'm trying to know actually what position(number) has been selected from user . And it is no case of applying of only two fragments . Actually What i'm doing , i'm changing the image inside fragments .